# Angular2 post and put requests not calling web api methods

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, put, angular2-services

I have a RegionService class in Angular 2, which has Add and Update Region methods. However, the post and put methods does not reach respective methods in Web API. I put the debug breakpoint in Web API methods but it doesn't reach there.

Here is the methods in RegionService class:

[image]
Here is the code for RegionApiController with post and put methods:

[image]

However, If I use postman to submit post and put, it stops at breakpoint in Web API methods and able to add/update region record successfully.

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps resolved the issues for me and I was able to get response from Web Api hosted on Server.

1) Added following NuGet packages for CORS

```html
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
```

2) Enabled CORS in WebApiConfig.cs file within WebAPI application -> inside Register() method

```
var enableCorsAttribute = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(enableCorsAttribute);
```

Note: the localhost url that you see in the question image was actually url hosted on server that I changed in my code prior to posting question here...

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Thank you so much. I was going crazy.

Comment: Does any one have other ideas why the above implementation does not work? I have the CORS but still the PUT is not called. The call does not even show in the network tab off the browser.